# Reach a VPN client from a host on private subnet on AWS VPC

Tags: networking, vpn, routing, openvpn, amazon-web-services

I have a setup like the one on turnkeylinux's github https://github.com/turnkeylinux-apps/openvpn/blob/master/docs/site-to-site.rst

I have a VPC with public and private subnets, and a NAT instance on the public subnet. On the public subnet I also have a openvpn server provided by a turnkeylinux AMI. Now, I have 2 vpn clients that connect remotely to the openvpn server in the VPC, and those clients have no problem reaching the private subnet.

I would like though for the hosts in the private subnet to reach the vpn clients, not the lan behind the clients.

```
VPC: 10.1.0.0/16
Public subnet: 10.1.0.0/24
  NAT: 10.1.0.2
  OVPN server: 10.1.0.3
Private subnet: 10.1.1.0/24
  A host on the private subnet is 10.1.1.4
```

VPN clients receive IPs in a `10.1.128.0/17` subnet.
So I have 2 clients with IPs: `10.1.128.6` and `10.1.128.10`

Now all clients can successfully reach `10.1.1.4`, but `10.1.1.4` cannot reach the `10.1.128.6` or `10.1.128.10`

Is it possible for the hosts in a private subnet to reach the actual vpn clients?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it's possible.

I had to add a route to the private subnet's route table which will route traffic to `10.1.128.0/17` by using the openvpn instance (10.1.0.3).

After that I had to add masquerading from eth0 to tun0 as well (on the ovpn server). tun0 to eth0 was already set. This is the command:

```
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o tun0 -j MASQUERADE
```

Comment: This was much easier than adding what I feel should be unnecessary stuff to the routing table on aws...

Comment: Can you show how to add the route in the private subnet route table.